# Pythonic way of single list with all variations of sublists

Tags: python, combinatorics

I'm sure there are answers to this simple question but I don't really know how to formulate it in English (ashamed), so decided to ask human beings.

Suppose I have a list of lists:

```
[['Sometimes'], [' '], ['I'], [' '], ['love', 'hate'], [' '], ['pizza', 'coke']]
```

What would be the most pythonic way to obtain the following output?

```
['Sometimes I love pizza', 'Sometimes I love coke', 'Sometimes I hate pizza', 'Sometimes I hate coke']
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

options = [['Sometimes'],[' '],['I'],[' '],['love','hate'],[' '],['pizza','coke']]

for combo in product(*options):
    print("".join(combo))
```

gives

```
Sometimes I love pizza
Sometimes I love coke
Sometimes I hate pizza
Sometimes I hate coke
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you! and also, I learnt how is it called now :)

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell You should explain the `product` method also.

Answer (score 1):

This can be written nicely with a recursive generator:

```
def sentences(lists, i=0, sentence=''):
    if i == len(lists):
        yield sentence
    else:
        for word in lists[i]:
            yield from sentences(lists, i + 1, sentence + word)
```

And then

```
lists = [['Sometimes'],[' '],['I'],[' '],['love','hate'],[' '],['pizza','coke']]
for s in sentences(lists):
    print s
```

which prints

```
Sometimes I love pizza
Sometimes I love coke
Sometimes I hate pizza
Sometimes I hate coke
```

---

(To get an actual list, `list(sentences(lists))`.)

Comment: thank you for your solution too! however, this one is less universal than posted above (works on 2.x too) and more one-line :)

Comment: @c0rdis, yes. It has value as a learning exercise, but since `itertools` has been included in the Python standard libraries, it makes most sense to use that.